# Return only match fields instead of returning the whole document

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elasticsearch-aggregation

Return only matched source instead of returning the whole document of elastic search that contain that text

Suppose I have a data in this format,

```
POST /bookdb_index/book/_bulk
{ "index": { "_id": 1 }}
{ "title": "Elasticsearch: The Definitive Guide", "authors": ["clinton gormley", "zachary tong"], "summary" : "A distibuted real-time search and analytics engine", "publish_date" : "2015-02-07", "num_reviews": 20, "publisher": "oreilly" }
{ "index": { "_id": 2 }}
{ "title": "Taming Text: How to Find, Organize, and Manipulate It", "authors": ["grant ingersoll", "thomas morton", "drew farris"], "summary" : "organize text using approaches such as full-text search, proper name recognition, clustering, tagging, information extraction, and summarization", "publish_date" : "2013-01-24", "num_reviews": 12, "publisher": "manning" }
{ "index": { "_id": 3 }}
{ "title": "Elasticsearch in Action", "authors": ["radu gheorge", "matthew lee hinman", "roy russo"], "summary" : "build scalable search applications using Elasticsearch without having to do complex low-level programming or understand advanced data science algorithms", "publish_date" : "2015-12-03", "num_reviews": 18, "publisher": "manning" }
{ "index": { "_id": 4 }}
{ "title": "Solr in Action", "authors": ["trey grainger", "timothy potter"], "summary" : "Comprehensive guide to implementing a scalable search engine using Apache Solr", "publish_date" : "2014-04-05", "num_reviews": 23, "publisher": "manning" }
```

I want to search text having guide in it .Instead of returning the whole document i want to have only those fields that contain the text query

```
GET /bookdb_index/book/_search?q=guide
```

when i run this it return me whole document .however i want to return only those fields that contain guide like in id 4 in summary guide is there so only summary field return and in id 1 in title guide is there so only title is return

Comment: Can I also find out the count of searched text in the document .I mean if i search quide can i count how many times the quide occur in each document and in which field.

Comment: I've added an answer for you, if you want to count how may times the `guide` string occurs in each document then you can count the occurrence of `<em>guide</em>` on which the string matches. Hope it helps, best of luck

Answer (score 2):

Usually we use `_source` filtering to specify which field we want after search but that not implies that all of the `_source` field matches my query string. But as you want only the field that matches your search query, for this case you can use **[highlight](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html)** feature of Elasticsearh along with `multi_match` this way,

```
GET /bookdb_index/book/_search
{
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": "guide",
            "fields": ["title", "summary"]
        }
    },
    "highlight": {
        "fields": {
            "title": {},
            "summary": {}
        }
    },
    "size": 10
}
```

When I run this on my elasticsearch index this is what I get as response, If you see carefully on the `highlight` field it will show which field is match with your query string i.e **guide** in this case and it also emphasis it with and `<em>Guide</em>` tag. For 1st document it matches the **summery** field and for 2nd one it matches the **title** field.

```
{
  "took": 84,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 1.3278645,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "bookdb_index",
        "_type": "book",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 1.3278645,
        "_source": {
          "title": "Solr in Action",
          "authors": [
            "trey grainger",
            "timothy potter"
          ],
          "summary": "Comprehensive guide to implementing a scalable search engine using Apache Solr",
          "publish_date": "2014-04-05",
          "num_reviews": 23,
          "publisher": "manning"
        },
        "highlight": {
          "summary": [
            "Comprehensive <em>guide</em> to implementing a scalable search engine using Apache Solr"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "bookdb_index",
        "_type": "book",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.2871116,
        "_source": {
          "title": "Elasticsearch: The Definitive Guide",
          "authors": [
            "clinton gormley",
            "zachary tong"
          ],
          "summary": "A distibuted real-time search and analytics engine",
          "publish_date": "2015-02-07",
          "num_reviews": 20,
          "publisher": "oreilly"
        },
        "highlight": {
          "title": [
            "Elasticsearch: The Definitive <em>Guide</em>"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```